# Error while creating a folder(project) using taza gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

hi when i try to create the folder(project) using the taza gem I am running into an following error

```
D:\>taza work
undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module
```

Comment: `taza` is not even [built properly](https://travis-ci.org/hammernight/taza) at the moment.

Comment: so what should be done to get resolve